# Not able to delete characters in zefyr flutter package

Tags: flutter, plugins, backspace

I am working on the blog post section I want formatters like bold, italic in text field.

So I have searched in stackoverflow they recommended Zefyr plugin.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/providerate();
    final document = _loadDocument();
    _controller = ZefyrController(document);
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  NotusDocument _loadDocument() {
    final Delta delta = Delta()..insert('\n');
    return NotusDocument.fromDelta(delta);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'New blog',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ZefyrScaffold(
        child: ZefyrEditor(
          controller: _controller,
          focusNode: _focusNode,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using zefyr: ^0.12.0 and quill_delta: ^1.1.3

After I can't delete characters so please I want to know any changes or any other way.

Thank you for stackoverflow and all developers.